# array.slice strange behaviour with nuxt-edge

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, nuxt.js, slice

**EDIT AND SOLVED:**
I've found the origin of the problem:
I thought arr.slice returned the new array but, actually, it returns the deleted element. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
The solution is simply to put the slice function before the bracket and not in it:

```
    remove (index) {
      const arrayCopy = this.liens.slice()
      arrayCopy.splice(index, 1)
      this.$emit('update:liens', arrayCopy)

    }
```

Thank you kissu for your time!

---

I was previously using nuxt 2.xx and since switching to nuxt-edge the vue behavior changed with array.slice. Let me explain :

My code is very basic and is used to add/remove items of an array in a child component "stockLiens". This array is passed to a parent component "currentEtabCommentUser" via .sync

Everything was working fine before but since I'm with nuxt-edge, if I have - for instance - an array of 3 items and I want to delete the 2nd one, it is the only item left!

My stockLiens component Javascript is the following:

```js
props: {
    liens: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
},
methods: {
    // I used concat() and slice() to avoid mutating a prop in the component
    add () {
      const arrayConcat = this.liens.concat([{ url: '', description: '' }])
      this.$emit('update:liens', arrayConcat)
    },
    remove (index) {
      const arrayCopy = this.liens.slice()
      console.log(this.liens) // line 108
      console.log(arrayCopy) // line 109
      this.$emit('update:liens', arrayCopy.splice(index, 1))
      console.log(arrayCopy) // line 111
    }
}
```

When I run the script, the text in the firefox console is the following:

[image: I'm not allowed to publish picture yet so it's a link]
On the picture, you can see that :

- stockLiens:108 is an array of 3 items (it makes sense since it is this.liens)
- stockLiens:109 is an array of 2 items! (strange since it's a simple array.slice() of this.liens) The 2 items are the old index 0 and the old index 2 (I've clicked on old index 1)
- stockLiens:111 is the same array that on line 109. (strange again because it should have been spliced in line 110)
- currentEtabCommentUser:186 is an array of 1 item : the old index 1 (since line 186 is just a listener on this.liens, it should be the same array that on stockLiens:111. I really don't understand anything!)

My currentEtabCommentUsercomponent:

```html
<stockLiens
   :liens.sync="liens"
/>

<script>
  watch: {
    liens () {
      console.log(this.liens) // line 186
    }
  }
</script>
```

I've tried to change .sync, to copy the array with for(i...), to get() / set(v) the liens property, ... I've looked on many forum during hours (2 days now) but I can't understand the problem.

Can someone help me please ?
Thank you in advance!

My stockLiens component HTML:

```html
<v-card
   v-for="(url, i) in liens"
  :key="i"
>
            <v-text-field
              v-model="url.url"
              label="Url"
            />
            <v-text-field
              v-model="url.description"
              label="Description"
            />
          <v-divider vertical />
          <v-btn
            icon
            @click="remove(i)"
          >
            <v-icon>mdi-delete-forever-outline</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
</v-card>
```

Comment: First of ne aware of the methods that mutate or not the previous array, `splice` does for example: https://doesitmutate.xyz/splice/ Then, don't use `console.log` to debug this kind of thing, either output the result into a `pre` tag step by step, use the JSON.parse(JSON.stringify trick or better, the Vue devtools to inspect the state. As you can see line 109, there is still an array of 3 elements even if you can see only two. Not sure about the prototype difference tho (maybe a Firefox thing). Use the old/new value with watch: https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#watch too.

Comment: Overall, using `console.log` has some gotchas, on top of mutating methods and so. Nothing looks wrong to me so far, just the output of the `console.log`. And as always, prefer either to isolate it into a more simpler JS vanilla playground (basics are important) or to use the Vue devtools to debug efficiently. Also, `.sync` can be a bit tricky but it's deprecated and not available in Vue3 btw so prefer using something more explicit instead like `:value and @input` (even if the issue is probably not coming from here).

Comment: Thank you @kissu for your answers. I've tried to change .sync ``by :value and @input```` before asking for help but the problem wa still there.

Comment: I've looked in vue DevTool for the state of the prop "links" but it is an array of 3 items before I clicked on "delete item(1)" and an array of 1 item (the old index 1) after I've clicked... I didn't learn many...
I'll try to reproduce the problem in a vanilla playground and edit my post if I know more.
I wonder if it can be a problem of babel compilation. Why did it work before and not now... ?

Comment: Haha, don't add babel to the thing (probably not that). Stay focused on the algorithm part and try to give us a [repro], that way we'll see what may be buggy. Probably something simple or a side effect.